# Django RelatedManager: Get currently selected element's value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model that has a `duration` value, and a `durations` object, which in turn has multiple `duration_mins` values inside. The root-level `duration` acts as a fallback if the `durations` object is empty.

Endpoint response is something like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Track Name X",
    "duration": 10,
    "durations": [
        {
            "id": 218,
            "duration_mins": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 219,
            "duration_mins": 15
        },
        {
            "id": 220,
            "duration_mins": 20
        }
    ]
}
```

The main idea is to have a sum of "Minutes listened". Right now, we are doing

`self.total_sec += single.duration`

Which correctly adds the fallback, root-level duration. What I want to do is add the current duration value (sent by the client). ie: if the user selected the 20 min. duration.

I tried the following:

```
if single.durations:
    self.total_sec += single.durations.get().duration_mins
else:
    self.total_sec += single.duration
```

Which obviously doesn't work, but explains what I'm trying to accomplish. The error I'm getting is either:

`AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'duration_in_minutes'`

or, if I append .get()

`[...]MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Duration -- it returned 3!`

Can anybody tell me how to get the currently selected duration? (Assuming the client is sending the corresponding duration id)

Thanks!

models.py (abridged)

```
class Duration(models.Model):
    single = models.ForeignKey('Single', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='durations')
    duration_mins = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(help_text='Single duration in minutes')

class Single(ActiveAndTimeRestrictedMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    duration = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(help_text='Single duration in minutes')

class Stat(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        'users.CustomUser', related_name='stats', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_seconds = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0, blank=True, help_text='Total seconds meditated')

    def reset(self):
        self.total_seconds = 0
        self.save()

    def update_after_finish(self, single, save=True):
        self.total_seconds += single.duration
        ...
```

serializers.py (abridged)

```
class SingleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    durations = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Single
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'duration', 'durations')

    def get_durations(self, obj):
        durations = obj.durations.all().order_by('duration_mins')
        return DurationSerializer(durations, many=True).data
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant models as well as the serializer?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sure! They're pretty big so I added the corresponding parts. Let me know if that works for you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get total secs of durations using aggregation for django models.

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
...
total = single.durations.filter(id=received_id).aggregate(total=Coalesce(Sum('duration_mins'), 0)))['total']
self.total_secs += total or single.duration
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I misstated the goal. Rather than adding all of the durations, I want django to get the current duration (received from the request, ie. 20), and add that value to the user''s secs. :) Something like Add single > durations > 1 > duration_mins to total_secs